# Window Decorations on Gnome Flashback not changing and emerald?

Tags: gnome, themes, window, emerald

I need some advice on how to change the window decorations in Ubuntu 15.10, when changing them in Tweak Settings only nautilus changes theme, the window decoration on everything else remains the default ubuntu ambiance setting.

Also I can't install emerald from anywhere? Are the PPA's dead?

Answer (score 6):

To change theme run this command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity theme "Ambiance"
```

Replace "Ambiance" with theme name you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands additionally to the above code.

Run these commands in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ambiance"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Ambiance"
```

As @albert mentioned change "Ambiance" with any theme you want to use.
For example,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Arc-Darker"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Arc-Darker"
```